# Kernel module for Cisco VPN client doesn't compile under ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, compiling, software-installation, kernel-modules, vpn

I am trying to install a Cisco VPN client under Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. In the extracted folder I type:

```
alex@alex-laptop:~/Downloads/cisco4.8/vpnclient$ sudo ./vpn_install
```

and there is output of activity which appears to end unsuccessfully with:

```
/home/alex/Downloads/cisco4.8/vpnclient/linuxcniapi.c:458: error: ‘struct sk_buff’ has no member named ‘nh’
make[2]: *** [/home/alex/Downloads/cisco4.8/vpnclient/linuxcniapi.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/alex/Downloads/cisco4.8/vpnclient] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-33-generic'
make: *** [default] Error 2
Failed to make module "cisco_ipsec.ko".
```

How can I find the problems in this installation? What actions should I take to correct the installation procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your kernel is too recent for the Cisco VPN client. You'll need to downgrade your kernel to a 2.6.30 version or below.

See the [release notes](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client48/release/notes/48client.html#wp1528719).

Comment: can you tell me how to do this down grade in an edit plz? And also the command to check the kernel edition? Can you tell me if this will cause me to lose data and state of the user?

Comment: Your kernel version is 2.6.32-33, it is visible in the log you posted (or type `uname -a`). I don't know how to downgrade a kernel on Ubuntu, but I'm sure you'll find some documentation if you search a bit.

Comment: if I install Debian instead, will this problem be fixed? If I install the stable version will that kernel not be too recent? I use Unetbootin (thanks)

Comment: In the end I used another vpn client, it is described in this post: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27506/1325

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-­get install network­-manager­-pptp 
sudo apt­-get install network­-manager­-vpnc
sudo apt-­get install network­-manager­-openvpn
```

then , follow this tuto:

http://snnyc.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/connecting-to-cisco-vpn-from-ubuntu-linux-12-04.pdf